# How to determine if an event already exists in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

This issue is because I'm changing my code to a form I think is more appropriate, as I do in AS3. I have a xmlhttprequest:

```
var httpReq = new http(); // creates de xmlhttprequest for the browser
httpReq.open('POST', url, true);
httpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"); 
httpReq._timeout = setTimeout(function(){ httpReq.abort(); }, 5000);
httpReq.addEventListener("someEvent", this.process, false); // LINE CHANGED
httpReq.send(dados);
```

The line I change was...

```
httpReq.onstatechange = function(){ etc... };
```

My first try was change to...

```
httpReq.addEventListener("statechange", this.process, false);
```

Just like onclick to "click" etc. using the old method of "attempt, succeed and fail". Ok, so I change the method and taken the right types of event in MDN guide. But I'm concerned with the fact of Safari and FireFox doesn't point the non existence of the "statechange" event for the object. If the string is not an event, it is just not fired in silence. So I'm wondering if there is an "event tester" to debug a large code, to find if there is support for the event by a specific browser, etc., help in the investigation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: Why do you need to use `addEventListener` instead of `onstatechange`?

Comment: I'm not an expert to tell you why, I'm following recommendations. In the Mozilla documentation (MDN), the example of how to handle xmlHttpRequest is by addEventListener, witch is the same as AS3 official documentation from Adobe. We'll need some ECMASCRIPT expert to tell us the reasons...